# Make pdf of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I was wondering if it is possible to turn a text inside a div into a pdf. In my code here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdNdXd when I select a few items they apear benith the text "U košarici se trenutno nalazi:", this is the div where all selected products appear, now what I want to do is, when I select products I want, I want to save them in pdf format so I can download it. So basicly what I want to do is get all items from the last div named cart to a pdf format. Tried with this code bellow but it didnt work.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple way using a xepOnline converter.

```
  <a href="#" onclick="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('your div name here',{render:'download'});">
       <p style="text-align:center;"><img src="/PDF.png" style="width:50px; height:50px;"/></p>
    </a>
```